# Transform/warp coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an array of coordinates that mark an area on the floor.

[image: points on a floor marking an area]

I want to generate a new array where all the coordinates are transformed, so that I get a warped array. The points should look like the following image. Please note that I want to generate the graphic **using** the new array. It does not exist yet. It gets generated after having to new array.

[image: a polygon that is the same as the first graphic, but warped/transformed]

I know the distance between all coordinates if it helps. The coordinates json looks like this, where `distance_to_next` contains the distance to the next point in cm:

```
[
  {
    "x": 295,
    "y": 228,
    "distance_to_next": 200
  },
  {
    "x": 559,
    "y": 263,
    "distance_to_next": 30
  },
  {
    "x": 551,
    "y": 304,
    "distance_to_next": 50
  },
  {
    "x": 473,
    "y": 290,
    "distance_to_next": 70
  },
  {
    "x": 451,
    "y": 352,
    "distance_to_next": 150
  },
  {
    "x": 249,
    "y": 313,
    "distance_to_next": 100
  }
]
```

The first point is always in the top left.

I'm using python and opencv2 and I know about various functions like `cv.warpAffine`,
`cv.warpPerspective`, `cv.findHomography`, `cv.perspectiveTransform`, etc, but I'm not sure which one to use here.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: you need to use cv.findHomography

Comment: @yannziselman but cv.findHomography needs two images and I only have the one. I want to generate the second using the homography. Does this even make sense?

Comment: cv.findHomography does not require two images. it requires two sets of points. one set is the locations of the keypoints on the first image and the second set is the locations you want to transform these key points to. just find the locations of the corresponding points in the diagram you show in your question

Comment: And the transformation will definitely be affine, not perspective.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan "affine"? can you explain that statement? it makes no sense.

Comment: I've updated the question to make clear that the graphic does not exist yet, so I can't find the points there to find the homography.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Basically, it means that the coordinates can be all multiplied by the same 3x3 matrix to get the desired result.

Comment: a general 3x3 matrix would be a perspective transform (not an affine one). this situation certainly calls for a perspective transform. I asked you because your statement does not follow from the given facts. I know what these things mean.

Comment: @yannziselman so far none of this got me further. any chance you can have a look again?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Affine is subset of perspective transformations. See for more details this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637472/opencv-transformationmatrix-affine-vs-perspective-warping

Comment: @Abhi25t True, I still however hope my meaning was clear to those concerned, like OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points in your coordinates json do not align with the white polygon. If I use them I get the green polygon as shown below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
 
# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('./input.jpg') 
 
# Create a copy of the image
img_copy = np.copy(img)
img_copy = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 
pts = np.array([[295,228],[559,263],[551,304],[473,290],[451,352],[249,313]], np.int32)
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
img_copy2 = cv2.polylines(img_copy,[pts],True,(0,255,0), thickness=3)
plt.imshow(img_copy2)
```

[image]

So I manually found the approx coordinates of your white polygon and overlayed them on white polygon in green. And **you need the coordinates of desired polygon**. I displayed them in red.

```
img = cv2.imread('./input.jpg') 
img_copy = np.copy(img)
img_copy = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

input_pts = np.array([[300,300],[890,380],[830,600],[200,480]], np.int32)
pts = input_pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
img_copy3 = cv2.polylines(img_copy,[pts],True,(0,255,0), thickness=3)

output_pts= np.array([[300,300],[850,300],[850,520],[300,520]], np.int32)
pts = output_pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
img_copy3 = cv2.polylines(img_copy3,[pts],True,(255,0,0), thickness=3)

plt.imshow(img_copy3)
```

[image]

We need to use `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform` here. But it takes **only 4 points** as input, so discard 2 points.

```
img = cv2.imread('./input.jpg') 
img_copy = np.copy(img)
img_copy = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

input_pts = np.float32(input_pts)
output_pts = np.float32(output_pts)

# Compute the perspective transform M
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(input_pts,output_pts)
 
# Apply the perspective transformation to the image
out = cv2.warpPerspective(img_copy,M,(img_copy.shape[1], img_copy.shape[0]),flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
 
# Display the transformed image
plt.imshow(out)
```

[image]